# Printing numbers - setTimeout JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I'm trying to print numbers to my div (scroll) from 0 -5, then 2s pause and then from 5-0. What's wrong ?

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 5;
var scroll = document.getElementById('scroll');

function start() {
  scroll.textContent += i;
  setTimeout(start, 2000)
  i++;
  if (i > 5) {
    setTimeout(start2, 2000)
    scroll.textContent = '';
  }
}

function start2() {
  scroll.textContent += j;
  setTimeout(start2, 2000)
  j--;
  if (j == 0) {
    setTimeout(start, 200)
  }

}

start();
```

```html
<div id="scroll"></div>
```

Comment: you call `setTimeout(start, 2000)` when you should not.... Same with your other function...

Comment: You should add conditions to both `setTimeout(start, 2000)` in `start` and to `setTimeout(start2, 2000)` in `start2`. Like for the first case, it should be called only when the `i <= 5`, otherwise it will be called forever.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var j = 5;
var scroll = document.getElementById('scroll');

function start() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= j; ++i)
    scroll.textContent += i;

  setTimeout(start2, 2000)
}

function start2() {
  for (let i = j; i; --i)
    scroll.textContent += i;

  setTimeout(start, 2000) // should you?
}

start();
```

```html
<div id="scroll"></div>
```